# 301 on ServerAlias goes to ServerName domain

Tags: apache, redirect, vhosts

I have the following virtual host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.something.com
  ServerAlias something1.com
  Include conf/vhost/www.something.com-rewrites.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Under the www.something.com-rewrites.conf file:

```
RewriteRule ^/apps/(.*)$ / [R=301,L,E=cache_redirect:1]
```

If  there is a request for `something1.com/apps/`, I see that the redirect is happening but the URL is getting changed to `www.something.com`

I don't understand this strange behavior and also is their any other way that I can prevent this behavior?

Comment: There's nothing strange about that behaviour, it's doing exactly what you told it to do... What are you actually *trying* to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying for some redirects on two domains pointing to the same docroot, so used one of them as a server alias and would still want to preserve the URL for 301 redirects for requests coming through the ServerAlias.

Comment: Please add an example of the what the URL should look like before and after the redirect. It's hard to understand what you're asking at the moment. Also try adding `http://%{HTTP_HOST}` to the rewrite destination

Comment: As given in the question, if I type 'something1.com/apps/', I should have been redirected to 'something1.com/' but instead I get redirected to 'www.something.com/'. I tried your previous comment but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you have a non-default value for UseCanonicalName OR your client is HTTP/1.0 and not sending a Host: header.

Answer (score 0):

If your site is running a CMS like wordpress, it uses the domain it was installed on as the Main domain and will redirect to that Main domain regardless of whatever your ServerAlias and ServerMain settings are.